# Connect Python to SQL Server from Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, pyodbc

My OS is Windows 10

I have SQL Server installed on my machine

I am trying to access SQL Server from Ubuntu bash

Here is my code

```
import pyodbc 

ConnectionString = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=DELLG3;DATABASE=R3;UID=sa;PWD=******;"

conn = pyodbc.connect(ConnectionString)
```

I am getting this error

```
asmgx@DELLG3:~$ python3 /mnt/c/py/28autosk.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/py/28autosk.py", line 58, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(ConnectionString)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I tried all these links to help me fix the problem and have been googling and trying to resolve the problem

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/python/ubuntu/?rtc=1

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147280/how-to-install-mssql-server-in-ubuntu-19-04

https://askubuntu.com/questions/462094/unable-to-install-libssl1-0-0i386-due-to-unmet-dependencies

Anyone can help me connect to SQL Server from Ubuntu?

Comment: What happens if you try to `ping DELLG3` from the Ubuntu box?

Comment: @GordThompson Pings ok.  PING DELLG3.localdomain (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from DELLG3.localdomain (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.139 ms

Comment: So `DELLG3` is resolving to 127.0.1.1, but that is probably not the IP address of the machine running the SQL Server instance. Can you find out what the other IP address is and try that as the `SERVER=` argument?

Comment: Ubuntu bash is running in my Windows 10.  so the ip 127.0.1.1 is SQL Server IP

Comment: Hmm, ok, if you run `ifconfig eth0` in bash and `ipconfig` in a Windows command prompt do you see the same "real" (not 127.x.y.z) IP address in each?

Comment: I tried all IPs in both such as 10.0.0.242 and still getting same timeout error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try that

`pyodbc.connect ('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dbname;UID=sa;PWD=********')`