# ODBC is not working in new cluster of Databricks

Tags: python, odbc, databricks, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc

server = 'serve'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
schema = 'schema'
database = 'database'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "samplesecrets", key = "sqluname")+';PWD='+ dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "samplesecrets", key = "sqlpassword"))
```

Error:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "samplesecrets", key = "sqluname")+';PWD='+ dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "samplesecrets", key = "sqlpassword"))
    
    Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

What I tried:

```
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

Error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
msodbcsql17 is already the newest version (17.8.1.1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 81 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up msodbcsql17 (17.8.1.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package msodbcsql17 (--configure):
 installed msodbcsql17 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 msodbcsql17
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The runtime version of databricks is 13.3

Pls help me how to erase this error. Thanks

Comment: it looks like it's a change in `pyodbc` or `unixodbc`

Comment: @AlexOtt idk how to do it.. u have some example code to try it on?

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68615355/connect-python-to-sql-server-from-ubuntu/71076441#71076441`

check that might help you fixing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you will need to upgrade ubuntu package version to **22.04**:
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

To check package version to use run:
%sh
cat /etc/*release

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this solves my issue, however, when I tried to restart the databricks cluster, the issue persists. what I have tried is to create init scripts, but databricks doesnt allow using DBFS files bcoz it's already deprecated. :(